# Geodesics in hyperboloid model of hyperbolic geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $X$ be the north sheet of the hyperboloid $ z^2=x^2+y^2+1$ and $g=dx^2+dy^2-dz^2$ a scalar product on the tangent space at every point. I have showed that $(X,g)$, is a Riemannian surface , both diffeomorphic and isometric to the Poincaré disk $\mathbb{D}=\{(x,y,0)\in \mathbb{R^3},x^2+y^2<1\}$ with the hyperbolic metric, via the stereographic projection from the point $q=(0,0,-1)$.

My question is this, I know that the geodesics on $\mathbb{D}$ (with the hyperbolic metric) are its diameters and its intersections with euclidian circles orthogonal to $S^1$ ,  and since stereographic projection is both bijective and an isometry, the geodesics on $X$ should be the preimages of geodesics on $\mathbb{D}$ under stereographic projection, i.e. intersections of the Hyperboloid with cones having a vertex at the point $q$ and whose cross section on $\mathbb{D}$ is a geodesic.

However I have read that geodesics on the hyperboloid model are its intersections with planes in $\mathbb{R^3}$ passing through the origin. How can you see that these two descriptions are equivalent?

Comment: Can you include some details to justify why "According to your solution" this only happens when the geodesic on $\mathbb D$ is one of the diameters? Perhaps then we can diagnose where you went wrong.

Comment: @LeeMosher All of what I wrote is "my solution", I had just worded the question very badly and made that clearly wrong assuption, based on absolutely nothing, it should now be more clear what I am not able to understand from the updated question.

Comment: You have to chase down very carefully how to go from the hyperboloid model to the Poincaré disk model. And yes, what you've read *is* correct.

Comment: @TedShifrin Is what I have deduced true though? And if it is, can one deduce that the geodesics are also intersections with planes through the origin simply by knowing what the geodesics in the Poincaré disk model? Or would one need another way to compute them?

Comment: There are diagrams in Hilbert and Cohn-Vossen that show the relationships among three or four models, one of which is Beltrami-Klein, taken as the disk $x^2 + y^2 < 1$ in the plane $z=1.$  The Poincare disc is  taken as the disk $x^2 + y^2 < 1$ in the plane $z=0.$ There are projections through the origin and projections through $(-1,0,0).$ The others are the hyperboloid, upper sheet, and the upper hemisphere of the standard unit sphere. See if I can find an image

Comment: @WillJagy Oh yes it makes sense, I think I found something similar as well now, I guess the description of geodesics via planes through the origin comes more naturally by projection from one of the other models then, right?

Comment: Stereographic projection is an isometry and therefore maps geodesics to geodesics. But it’s useful to prove directly that a curve on the hyperboloid is a geodesic if and only if it is the intersection of a linear 2-dimensional subspace with the hyperboloid.

Comment: The proof is exactly the same as the standard proof that great circles are the only geodesics on the standard sphere.

Comment: Yes, to amplify a bit on what Deane said, one way of seeing that the intersections of the sphere with planes through the origin are geodesics is this: There is an isometry (reflection) of the sphere fixing precisely that submanifold; local uniqueness of geodesics leads to the observation that the fixed-point set must therefore be a geodesic (more generally, totally geodesic). Now how do you switch from $O(3)$ and the sphere to $O(2,1)$ and the hyperboloid?

Comment: @TedShifrin Unfortunately I am not too familiar with $O(2,1)$ . However I would guess that rotations fixing the z axis are there, which means that by the arguement you mentioned all of the intersections with vertical planes are geodesic (I guess this was already possible to see with the diameters of the disk). These are all the geodesics through $(0,0,1)$ . I would guess the other planes are also in the orbit of these vertical planes under $O(2,1)$ (this could be totally wrong and I apologize in advance) and we should be done.  I am not sure how one would go about this last part though.

Comment: $O_+(2,1)$ is the group of matrices $A$ preserving the Lorentz metric, hence acts on the "upper hyperboloid" if we specify that $a_{33}>0$ (hence the $+$). (So $A^\top LA = L$ where $L=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 \\ &1\\ &&-1\end{matrix}\right]$.) Given a plane $\Pi$, You want an $L$-orthonormal basis $v_1,v_2,v_3$ so that $v_1,v_2$ span $\Pi$, $Av_1=v_1$, $Av_2=v_2$, and $Av_3=-v_3$. Taking $-A$ if necessary, we have $A\in O_+(2,1)$ and this will do it.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much, this has been very instructive.